# Open the third-party app file directory report 'requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs'

Tags: android, file

First I requested permission for the file directory

```
private void requestFileTreePermission() {
        String uri = "content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3AAndroid%2Fdata%2Fcom.example.app%2Ffiles%2Ftest.png";
        Uri parse = Uri.parse(uri);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
        intent.addFlags(
                Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                        | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
                        | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION
                        | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PREFIX_URI_PERMISSION);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, parse);
        }
        activity.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_FOR_DIR);
    }
```

in onActivityResult

```
                context.getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
```

then open file

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);

intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3AAndroid%2Fdata%2Fcom.example.app%2Ffiles%2Ftest.png"), mimeType);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

This is an error message
`java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.externalstorage.ExternalStorageProvider uri content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3AAndroid%2Fdata%2Fcom.example.app%2Ffiles%2F20230830.3a0d57cd-bd7d-2a5e-27e5-7723c4b21160.png from pid=19575, uid=10181 requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs`

This problem has troubled me for a long time, why?

Comment: `I requested permission for the file directory` No. That is code to let the user select a directory.

Comment: `intent.addFlags(....)` You better remove that flag setting code as it serves nothing and has no effect. Its only confusing for readers.

Comment: `requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` Well did you? You didn't! You builded up an uri. That is not the way to go.

Comment: Already for Android 12 Google closed the hack to select app specific directories in Android folder. (or was it 13?).